# Does Revelation 19:1 affirm some portion of Jesus prayer to the Father in Matthew 6?

Tags: matthew, revelation

Revelation 19:1 YLT

And after these things I heard a great voice of a great multitude in the heaven, saying, 'Alleluia! the salvation, and the glory, and the honour, and the power, is to the Lord our God;

Matthew 6:16 YLT

And mayest Thou not lead us to temptation, but deliver us from the evil, because Thine is the reign, and the power, and the glory -- to the ages. Amen.

Comment: I think Matthew 6:13.  [The doxology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_6:13#The_doxology)  may not have been in a few of the early sources

Comment: μὴ εἰσενέγκῃς ἡμᾶς εἰς πειρασμόν On the exegesis of this it is worthwhile to consult: Jeffery Gibson Oxford,  D.Phil, The Temptations of Jesus in Early Christianity and The Disciples' Prayer: The Prayer Jesus Taught in Its Historical

Answer (score 1):

First, I note that both texts quoted by the OP use the Textus Receptus.  "Lord" does not appear in UBS5/NA28 text nor the Byzantine text of Rev 19:1.  The source of "Lord" here is possibly a copy of the same idea in V6.

Further, the doxology to the Lord's prayer in Matt 6 is a feature of the Byzantine text and not the NA28/UBS5 text.

However, for the sake of this question let us assume the TR is correct.

Of course, the doxology of Jesus' model prayer is affirmed in many places such as:

- Rev 19:1, 6 - After this I heard a sound like the roar of a great multitude in heaven, shouting: “Hallelujah! Salvation and glory and power belong to our God! ... “Hallelujah! For the Lord our God the Almighty reigns. Let us rejoice and be glad and give Him the glory.
- Rev 16:7 - And I heard the altar reply: “Yes, Lord God Almighty, true and just are Your judgments.”
- Rev 15:3, 4 - and they sang the song of God’s servant Moses and of the **Lamb**: “Great and wonderful are Your works, O Lord God Almighty! Just and true are Your ways, O King of the nations! Who will not fear You, O Lord, and glorify Your name? For You alone are holy. All nations will come and worship before You, for Your righteous acts have been revealed.”
- Rev 11:15 - The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our Lord and of His Christ, and He will reign forever and ever.”
- Rev 4:11 - “Worthy are You, our Lord and God, to receive glory and honor and power, for You created all things; by Your will they exist and came to be.”
- Rev 5:13 - “To Him who sits on the throne and to the Lamb be praise and honor and glory and power forever and ever!”

Interestingly, similar praises are offered to Jesus as the Lamb on the throne:

- Rev 15:3, 4 - and they sang the song of God’s servant Moses and of the **Lamb**: “Great and wonderful are Your works, O Lord God Almighty! Just and true are Your ways, O King of the nations! Who will not fear You, O Lord, and glorify Your name? For You alone are holy. All nations will come and worship before You, for Your righteous acts have been revealed.”
- Rev 12:10 - “Now have come the salvation and the power and the kingdom of our God, and the authority of His Christ.
- Rev 11:15 - The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our Lord and of His Christ, and He will reign forever and ever.”
- Rev 5:12 - “Worthy is the Lamb, who was slain, to receive power and riches and wisdom and strength and honor and glory and blessing!”
- Rev 5:13 - “To Him who sits on the throne and to the **Lamb** be praise and honor and glory and power forever and ever!”

I also note that following the Lamb's enthronement described in Rev 5, the throne is subsequently described as as jointly belonging to God and the Lamb in:

- Rev 22;1 - Then the angel showed me a river of the water of life, as clear as crystal, flowing from **the throne of God and of the Lamb**
- Rev 22:3 - No longer will there be any curse. The **throne of God and of the Lamb** will be within the city, and His servants will worship Him.

Comment: It's a well written summary, but this doesn't feel like it's clearly framed as an answer to the question. Is it intended to be more of a rebuttal to the OP's theological viewpoints?

Comment: @Stevecanhelp - It is intended to show that the doxology to the Lord's prayer is confirmed in many places (not just Rev 19:1) and the same rhetoric is applied also to Christ.

Comment: That's good - I was a bit surprised you didn't actually give a clear affirmative answer to the question that has been posed, though, which really should be the area of focus. As a community we aim to provide clear answers to specific questions, and avoid turning textual questions into theological debates. It's important to weigh this fairly and consistently across the user base, being cautious of our own biases.